# Substatus should not default to 'resolved' when SR status is set to 'closed'

Tags: siebel

I have a requirment on Siebel CRM. The client does not want the SubStatus field to be set to resolved when the Status field is set to closed. This is the default behaviour on Siebel vanilla, how do I change it? I have tried using Siebel Tools. Is it a workflow process?

The business component is Service Request and the applet is Service Request Detailed Applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is class behaviour. I tried bc user properties, runtime events and scripting, and there is no way to retain the value of Sub-Status to it's old value when the Status is set to closed. When the SR is closed, the Sub-Status is auto set to 'Resolved'

Workaround1: If your customer does not want the value 'Resolved'there, you can inactivate that value in the LOV (LOV_TYPE='SR_SUB_STATUS'). The SR can now be closed, the Sub-Status will remain blank because the 'Resolved' value cannot be found. You can ask the user to choose the value 'Completed' for Sub-Status, if they want to set it themselves.

Workaround2: If your requirement is to never have a Sub-Status value if Status='Closed', you could try to make Sub-Status field blank when that happens.

```
    function BusComp_PreWriteRecord()
    {

        if (this.GetFieldValue("Status") == "Closed")
        {
            this.SetFieldValue("Sub-Status", "");
        }
        return (ContinueOperation);
    }
```

But then Sub-Status can never be set when Status='Closed'

Workaround3: Maybe you have a Workflow which automatically closes a Service Request when certain conditions are met, but then Sub-Status is auto set to 'Resolved' and you want to prevent that. In this case, you can modify that WF/BS to set a different value in Sub-Status.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, it will be via BusComp User Properties. Under Service Request BC, check the BC User properties, query for *esolv* in "Values". You might get the Property which automatically sets "Sub-Status" when the "Status" field is changed. If you find that, you could simply inactivate that record.

If its not here, then check the RunTime events in the Application. You will have to check for SetField event under SR BC, see if any of those event Invokes the SET method of the BC.

Comment: thabks but its not in the BC user properties.. I dont understand the RunTime events in the application

Comment: lawal, I checked with colleagues here and we think this is vanilla behaviour in the CSSBCServiceRequest class files. It may be possible to override it. You could try adding a new BC User Property "On Field Update Set <Num>" with value: "Status", "Sub-Status", "Sub-Status"  . So that the Sub-status value is retained. I don't have a working setup here to test this on my side, let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks so much Ranjith, but it didnt work ..I think the state moduel or work flow process is to powerful to BC user properties, I also tried changing the post default value at business component to empty but it did not work either.. you can download siebel client and siebel tools and a sample database at oracle edelivery free.

Comment: I tried "Status", "Sub-Status", "Submitted", "IIF([Status]="Closed", "Y", "N")"

Comment: lawal, looks like this is class behaviour, I too tried various options and each had its own error, you will have to use scripting , see below.

Comment: Thanks Its class behaviour, but I cant see anything below. I read from the siebel bookshelf that it is class behaviour. please what is the script you wanted me to see below

Comment: sorry, mate. Been busy at work. This class behaviour cannot be overriden , I tried various approaches. Please see second answer if any of those workarounds will work for you.

Comment: Thanks so so much I understand you are busy, but please how do I implement the second approach. The work around 2 everything you have said makes lot of sense and i understand and I appreciate.                      so how do I implement work around 2 ?? by scripting??

Comment: Yes, it is Server Script at Business Component level, on "Service Request" BC. Add the code in the BusComp_PreWriteRecord event and test it out.